# Regex not matching data and dates

Tags: regex, perl

I have an SQL Select dump with many lines each looks like this:

```
07/11/2011 16:48:08,07/11/2011 16:48:08,'YD','MANUAL',0,1,'text','text','text','text',,,,'text',,,0,0,
```

I want to do 2 things to each line:

1. Replace all dates with Oracle's `sysdate` function. Dates can also come without hour (like `07/11/2011`).
2. Replace all null values with `null` string

Here's my attempt:

```
$_ =~ s/,(,|\n)/,null$1/g;                  # Replace no data by "null"
$_ =~ s/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/d{4}.*?,/sysdate,/g;  # Replace dates by "sysdate"
```

But this would transform the string to:

```
07/11/2011 16:48:08,07/11/2011 16:48:08,'YD','MANUAL',0,1,'text','text','text','text',null,,null,'text',null,,0,0,null
```

while I expect it to be

```
sysdate,sysdate,'YD','MANUAL',0,1,'text','text','text','text',null,null,null,'text',null,null,0,0,null
```

I don't understand why dates do not match and why some `,,` are not replaced by `null`.

Any insights welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the correct, expected output.

Comment: for me your date substitution works, however, your null problem seems to be that the second comma is actually consumed by the first match so when it continues looking for the next match it starts from the comma after that leaving you with the 2 in a row.

Comment: Can these 'text' fields contain quoted commas?

Comment: @FailedDev: sorry, fixed the question. Lucas: right, that seems the issue. TLP: nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\d{2}\/\d{2}\/d{4}.*?,` didn't work because the last `d` wasn't escaped.
If a `,` can be on either side, or begin/end of string, you could do it in 2 steps:

*step 1*
`s/(?:^|(?<=,))(?=,|\n)/null/g`
**expanded:**

```
/
  (?:  ^           # Begining of line, ie: nothing behind us
     | (?<=,)      # Or, a comma behind us
  )
     # we are HERE!, this is the place between characters
  (?=  ,           # A comma in front of us
     | \n          # Or, a newline in front of us
  )
/null/g
# The above regex does not consume, it just inserts 'null', leaving the
# same search position (after the insertion, but before the comma).

# If you want to consume a comma, it would be done this way:
s/(?:^|(?<=,))(,|\n)/null$1/xg
# Now the search position is after the 'null,'
```

*step 2*
`s/(?:^|(?<=,))\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}.*?(?=,|\n)/sysdate/g`

Or, you could combine them into a single regex, using the eval modifier:
`$row =~ s/(?:^|(?<=,))(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}.*?|)(?=,|\n)/ length $1 ? 'sysdate' : 'null'/eg;`

Broken down it looks like this

```
s{
   (?: ^ | (?<=,) )  # begin of line or comma behind us
   (                 # Capt group $1
       \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}.*?     # date format and optional non-newline chars
     |                          # Or, nothing at all
   )                 # End Capt group 1
  (?= , | \n )       # comma or newline in front of us
}{
   length $1 ? 'sysdate' : 'null'
}eg
```

If there is a chance of non-newline whitespace padding, it could be written as:

`$row =~ s/(?:^|(?<=,))(?:([^\S\n]*\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}.*?)|[^\S\n]*)(?=,|\n)/ defined $1 ? 'sysdate' : 'null'/eg;`

Comment: Thanks so much! The date substitution works fine, I just forgot to escape last d. If you can please explain the first regex, that would be awesome. Thanks again!

Comment: I prefer having separate regexes for legibility. Thanks again!

Comment: @m0skit0 - The post is modified to explain the comma regex. Doing it in 2 steps is fine as long as the regex's don't interfere with one another, which can be done by design.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
$ cat perlregex.pl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $row = "07/11/2011 16:48:08,07/11/2011 16:48:08,'YD','MANUAL',0,1,'text','text','text','text',,,,'text',,,0,0,\n";

print( "$row\n" );
while ( $row =~ /,([,\n])/ ) { $row =~ s/,([,\n])/,null$1/; }
print( "$row\n" );
$row =~ s/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}.*?,/sysdate,/g;
print( "$row\n" );
```

Which results in this:

```
$ ./perlregex.pl
07/11/2011 16:48:08,07/11/2011 16:48:08,'YD','MANUAL',0,1,'text','text','text','text',,,,'text',,,0,0,

07/11/2011 16:48:08,07/11/2011 16:48:08,'YD','MANUAL',0,1,'text','text','text','text',null,null,null,'text',null,null,0,0,null

sysdate,sysdate,'YD','MANUAL',0,1,'text','text','text','text',null,null,null,'text',null,null,0,0,null
```

This could certainly be optimized, but it gets the point across.

Comment: What if one of the 'text' fields contains commas? E.g. `'foo,,,bar'`.

Comment: @TLP, good point, and if thats the case, I would switch to using a package to handle parsing then put back together myself.  In the past i have used Text::CSV to accomplish this.  It should be sufficient here, you would just read in each row and then write a new row substituting values as needed.

Comment: @TLP good point, but text fields do not contain commas as far as I know.

Comment: @Lucas: thanks, good answer. I prefer sln's though, which has no loop.

Answer (score 1):

You want to replace something. Usually lookaheads are a better option for this :

```
$subject =~ s/(?<=,)(?=,|$)/null/g;
```

**Explanation :**

```
"
(?<=       # Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind)
   ,          # Match the character “,” literally
)
(?=        # Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
              # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      ,          # Match the character “,” literally
   |          # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      \$          # Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
)
"
```

Secodnly you wish to replace the dates :

```
$subject =~ s!\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}.*?(?=,)!sysdate!g;
```

That's almost the same with your original regex. Just replace the last , with lookahead. (If you don't want to replace it , don't match it.)

```
# \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}.*?(?=,)
# 
# Match a single digit 0..9 «\d{2}»
#    Exactly 2 times «{2}»
# Match the character “/” literally «/»
# Match a single digit 0..9 «\d{2}»
#    Exactly 2 times «{2}»
# Match the character “/” literally «/»
# Match a single digit 0..9 «\d{4}»
#    Exactly 4 times «{4}»
# Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
#    Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
# Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=,)»
#    Match the character “,” literally «,»
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanation. Why should I correct second regex if it works? I just forgot to escape last d... :P

Comment: You *shouldn't* correct it but usually I tend to avoid matching things that I don't want to modify. It's a good practice.

Comment: Thanks but my question has to do more about "why my original regex does not match what I need" :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe .*? is too greedy, try:

```
$_ =~ s/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/d{4}[^,]+,/sysdate,/g;
```

Comment: The issue was that last d wasn't escaped. Stupid mistake. Thanks for the answer :)